# Rails custom validation gets called from another validation in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec

I have a custom validation for my Rails app. I'm using `validate_uniqueness_of` in RSpec, and my tests are failing. When I look at the error, it says `bad value for range`.

Upon further inspection, it seems like whenever `validate_uniqueness_of` is called, it also calls my custom validation. And it puts the param its testing as `nil`.

How can I prevent this collision from happening?

### Model

```
class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :button, :link
  validates_uniqueness_of :start_date, :end_date
  validate :overlapping_start_dates, :overlapping_end_dates

  def date_range
    start_date..end_date
  end

  def overlapping_start_dates
    # binding.pry
    errors.add(:start_date, "cannot overlap with another announcement") unless self.class.where(start_date: start_date..end_date).empty?
  end

  def overlapping_end_dates 
    errors.add(:end_date, "cannot overlap with another announcement") unless self.class.where(end_date: start_date..end_date).empty?
  end 
end
```

### RSpec

```
describe Announcement do
  before { FactoryGirl.create(:announcement) }

  it { should validate_uniqueness_of :start_date }
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of :end_date }
  it { should validate_presence_of :button }
  it { should validate_presence_of :link }

  context 'when two announcements overlap' do
    it "should not save" do
      announcement = FactoryGirl.build(:announcement)
      expect(announcement.save).to eq(false) 
    end
  end

  after { Announcement.destroy_all }

end
```

Comment: Are `overlapping_start/end_dates` suppose to be callbacks?

Comment: Can you provide the error you get? There are not enough details here to move further. FWIW `validate_uniqueness_of` is not RSpec. I'm going to guess you are using the shoulda-matchers gem by Thoughtbot which provides that matcher.

Comment: @AaronK I am using the shoulda-matchers.

Comment: Still need to know the error you are getting or more details on why this is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I figured it out.

From the `validates_uniqueness_of` [file](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validate_uniqueness_of_matcher.rb):

> #### Caveat
>
> This matcher works a bit differently than other matchers. As noted before, **it will create an instance of your model if one doesn't already exist**. Sometimes this step fails, especially if you have database-level restrictions on any attributes other than the one which is unique. In this case, the solution is to populate these attributes with values before you call `validate_uniqueness_of`.

I was creating the FactoryGirl object for every test instead of building it.

### Working Code

```
describe Announcement do
  # before(:all) { FactoryGirl.create(:announcement) }
  subject { FactoryGirl.build(:announcement) } 
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of :start_date }
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of :end_date }
  it { should validate_presence_of :button }
  it { should validate_presence_of :link }

  context 'when two announcements overlap' do
    it "should not save" do
      FactoryGirl.create(:announcement)
      announcement = FactoryGirl.build(:announcement)
      expect(announcement.save).to eq(false) 
    end
  end

  after { Announcement.destroy_all }

end
```